# To "give something a boost" in German

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

I was wondering if you could help me properly express "to give something a boost" in German, where this generally means to "improve" or "re-energize". I was always under the impression that "etwas (dat.) Auftrieb geben" was the general translation, but I was told that my use of it sounded unnatural in the following context:

1. Als Athlet, wenn du gesünder isst, wird das deiner Leistung Auftrieb geben.

I was hoping to say that this would "give a boost to your performance", but was told this was not a correct usage of "Auftrieb geben". Can somebody explain why? On the internet, I see examples such as "Diese Entscheidung soll der Wirtschaft Auftrieb geben", and "Der Gewinn hatte der Mannschaft moralischen Auftrieb gegeben", so I am a bit confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Translation of 'give something a boost' depends also on the context. There are various possible translations in addition to the one you mentioned such as 'ankurbeln' (often economy), '(ver)stärken', 'Impuls/Schub geben' and a few more.

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to say, "the athlete wanted to give her performance a boost", would "ihrer Leistung Auftrieb geben" be a suitable translation?

Comment: You would never really say that. "Die Athletin wollte ihre Leistung steigern" sounds pretty natural. You could also look up definitions or synonyms (cambridge dictionary for instance). "Boost" in general is about improving or increasing something (long or short term).

Answer (score 9):

## einer Sache einen Schub geben

Auftrieb würde verstanden werden, aber Auftrieb ist ja v.a. aus der Luftfahrt bekannt. Die Wirtschaft stellt ihre Zahlen oft als Graph dar, wo ein Anstieg etwas Positives bedeutet. Bei Leistung passt der Anstieg nicht so gut, solange man diese nicht in PS misst.

Sehr verbreitet ist *einen Schub geben*.

> Als Athlet, wenn du gesünder isst, wird das deiner Leistung einen Schub geben.

Aber den Satz stellen wir noch um:

> Wenn Du als Athlet gesünder isst, wird das deiner Leistung einen Schub geben.